# how to locate first image and action on another element at the same command

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

at the listing page, i want to locate the last bottom item (maybe use the image class), and click on the remove button.
possible to use one line command to achieve it?

i have this class which is common

```
    class="sc-product-image"
```

and this is the remove element which working fine

```
    css=.sc-action-delete input
```

Comment: You need to provide more html. What is the relation between the item and the delete button?

Comment: Why would you need to do two separate actions in one command? Have you tried them separately? If you have, show us what have you tried.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be combined. It's for selenium Web driver..I used click then command to locate CSS and it works. But I wanted to locate exact item which I can think of using the img class to identify. Not sure if I'm right. Anyone has suggestion please let me know. Just wanted to remove the exact item from listing page.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to delete the last product by clicking on the delete corresponding to the product. In order to provide the correct answer we need the html of the entire last product parent element that have both the elements. Then it's possible to provide a xpath which can achieve your request.

Comment: I found the answer by myself by using the CSS locator and the number of child.